# Vue JS Component Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new in vue js, I am learning components. I have created a basic program containing component. Following are my files

project/src/main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
window.Vue = Vue;

import ButtonCounter from './components/ButtonCounter.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    render: h => h(ButtonCounter)
})
```

project/src/components/ButtonCounter.vue

```
<template>
<div id="components-demo">
<button-counter></button-counter>
</div>
</template>

<script>
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})
</script>
```

When I execute this, I get following error, even though I have declared Vue globally in main.js

[image]

Comment: JS modules are _independent_ chunks of code. So if you need to use `Vue` in the module, you'd have to import it inside the module.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you took the component definition and just moved to another file. If you move to another file you don't need to use `Vue.component`. You just `export` an object containing the data, methods, etc. that you want attached to the component. And inside the `Vue` instance you attach the imported component via the `components` property. I.e.

Main index.html

```
<div id="components-demo">
  <button-counter></button-counter>
</div>
```

Component.vue

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Then inside your main file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
// window.Vue = Vue; -- don't need this anymore

import ButtonCounter from './components/ButtonCounter.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    render: h => h(ButtonCounter),
    components: {ButtonCounter}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line

```
window.Vue = Vue;
```

Just import and create a new instance of Vue

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ButtonCounter from './components/ButtonCounter.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#components-demo',
    render: h => h(ButtonCounter)
})
```